# iOS Bookmark icon

Tags: html, ios

I've been able to set it so that when I add the site to an iOS homescreen the proper icon shows. It also shows in any web browser. However, when I use iOS Safari, go to the site, book mark it to the bookmark list, a C shows for the icon. I want our icon to show just like it does for   [www.apple.com](http://www.apple.com) or
[www.sunsetwx.com](http://www.sunsetwx.com) 
This is our site:  [www.cbcexeter.org](http://www.cbcexeter.org) that I'm using:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png?v=kPgOnJYLYR">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png?v=kPgOnJYLYR">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png?v=kPgOnJYLYR">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json?v=kPgOnJYLYR">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg?v=kPgOnJYLYR" color="#bd4c4c">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png?v=kFginJYoYs">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

I've tried .ico and it hasn't worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thank you for your question. It made me check out my own site and I found you were right. My fav icon wasn't showing in Safari. Instead there was a default icon with the starting letter of my site.

After a quick search I found this awesome page: http://realfavicongenerator.net/

Not only you can check your existing icons, it also lets you upload your icon and test it agains various devices/systems. Then replace singe images (e. g. i have a colored png for iOS homescreen but a monochrom vector for the safari bookmark and yet another one for android).

Then just generate and download the icon pack and upload it to your server, include the generated code in the `<head>` of your page and you are good to go.

**UPDATE**

For me it looks like it is working with your site now:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have used that site, which is excellent, however, Safari continues to do the same thing. Can you try it on your device (our site)?

Comment: I checked both, homscreen and bookmark and for me it seems to work (see update of my original answer)

Comment: Huh, it still doesn't work for me but maybe it's just a bad cache. Thank you for testing and your help.

Comment: It seems though that you might have made a mistake when setting the svg icon for safari because it has a white background (except that is what you want). If you only want the outline, make sure your svg has a transparent background

Comment: How is it that it's working for you in Safari? I'll look at fixing the SVG now.

Comment: Can you confirm http://realfavicongenerator.net/ is still doing its job? I do not see my icons on chrome (Windows nor Android). No 404 or errors.

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend using http://realfavicongenerator.net/. It automates the whole thing and generates the icons as well as copy-paste code and instructions to set it up.